# Rails object deleted in development, but apparently not in production. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have a bunch of `College` objects.  I print them all out here: http://www.collegeanswerz.com/colleges.  (excluding the alphabetical tab.  for that I hand coded the HTML)

Take the `Rank` tab as an example. (The `Size` and `Table` tabs are analogous to this code.)

```
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="national_universities2" class="tab-pane active">
            <h3>National Universities</h3>
            <nav class="list">
                <ol>
                    <% @national_university_rank.each do |school| %>
                        <li value="<%= school.us_news_ranking %>"><%= link_to school.name, '/'+school.url %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ol>
            </nav>
            <br />
            <p class="usnews">Ranks according to <%= link_to "US News", "http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges" %>.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="liberal_arts_colleges2" class="tab-pane">
            <h3>Liberal Arts Colleges</h3>
            <nav class="list">
                <ol>
                    <% @liberal_arts_college_rank.each do |school| %>
                        <li value="<%= school.us_news_ranking %>"><%= link_to school.name, '/'+school.url %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ol>
            </nav>
            <br />
            <p class="usnews">Ranks according to <%= link_to "US News", "http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges" %>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There are a couple of colleges that I deleted using `rails console`.  They aren't showing up in the development version of this web page, but they are in the production version.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've figured this out already, but it's probably because you deleted them in development which means the development database which *is not* the same as the production database (in a typical rails setup).  Each environment has its own database.  If they look the same it's because you (or a previous developer) cloned databases from one environment to another for testing or other purposes.

If you want to remove them from production, you need to get on that machine (wherever it's hosted) and run the same steps you ran in development to remove those records.

Comment: No, I actually haven't figured this out yet, but what you said makes sense. I'm using heroku, do you know how I would go about deleting them on my production database?

Comment: You can run a rails console on heroku just like you can on your development system.  `heroku run console --app=<your heroku app name>`.  Check out heroku's toolbelt/cli documentation https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ for more info